# dijit button not firing first time

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form, dijit.layout

I have a dijit/form/button that is added to a dijit/layout/ContentPane.  The dijit/layout/ContentPane is then placed within a dijit/form/DropDownButton.  When I click on the dijit/form/button it does not fire the first time.  For this example, I'm just having the button click generate an alert box with the value typed into the ValidationTextBox.  I've seen some discussion on this topic in other forums suggesting that a onMouseDown event or focus event is canelling out the first onClick event.  What is the best way to test for when these events have loaded or am I simply missing something in the code for dijit/form/button?  Thanks for having a look.

```js
dojoConfig = {
  parseOnLoad: true
}

require(["dijit/form/DropDownButton", "dijit/MenuItem", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox", "dijit/form/Button"],
  function(DropDownButton, DropDownMenu, ContentPane, ValidationTextBox, Button) {

    var parcelsearchCP = new ContentPane({
      id: 'parcelsearchCP',
      tabindex: 0
    });

    var parcelsearchInput = new ValidationTextBox({
      title: "Enter Parcel ID",
      name: "parcelvalue",
      id: "parcelsearchInput",
      placeholder: "<enter 8 digits>",
      regExp: "^[0-9]*$"
    });

    var searchBtn = new Button({
      //iconClass: "mySearchIcon",
      name: "searchme",
      label: "click me"
    });
    searchBtn.startup();
    dojo.place("<div>Enter Parcel ID: </div>", parcelsearchCP.containerNode);
    dojo.place(parcelsearchInput.domNode, parcelsearchCP.containerNode);
    dojo.place(searchBtn.domNode, parcelsearchCP.containerNode);

    var button = new DropDownButton({
      label: "hello!",
      name: "programmatic2",
      dropDown: parcelsearchCP,
      id: "progButton"
    }, "dropDownButtonContainer").startup();

    dojo.connect(searchBtn, "onClick", function() {
      var boxentry = dijit.byId("parcelsearchInput");
      if (boxentry.value !== "" || parcelsearchInput.isValid() === true) {
        alert(boxentry.value);

      } else {
        alert("Please enter a valid 8 digit number and re-submit.");
      }

    });


  });
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="dropDownButtonContainer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's showing an alert on the first click in Chrome, FF, and IE 11 for me...  What browser are you seeing the problem in?  Also, what version of Dojo are you actually using?  You're referencing 1.10's code but 1.5's styles in this example...

Comment: Hi Ken, I'm using Chrome Version 45.0.2454.99 to test but I will need to have this functionality work in FF and IE as well.  This code is actually a subset of a Javascript/HTML 5 template provided by a 3rd party vendor with their own api built upon Dojo 1.10.4.  I'm basically trying to add a "widget" to an existing application andstay in line with the existing coding standards of the application.  I realize this isn't really how it's done anymore and this is pretty much a legacy coding methodolgy by Dojo standards.  I wish I could start over but it's not up to me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Well as it turns out, all I had to do was change the event from "onClick" to "onMouseDown" and add a searchBtn.focus() in the button connect statement. That seemed to do the trick.  Thanks for your time!